# Cannot compile, Unable to execute dex, cannot merge, non-jumbo instruction

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik, dex

I'm needing some help because I can't get the solution by my own, I had read a lot of post and investigating a lot but without solution.

I've a proyect that have some subprojects ( actionbar,sliding,facebook,etc.. ) and when I try to compile it I receive following error all times.

```
[2013-07-31 14:44:06 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 67109 into a non-jumbo instruction!
[2013-07-31 14:44:06 - ojiva] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 67109 into a non-jumbo instruction!
```

I'm using Eclipse with latest ADT and latest tools ( r22 ) with latest SDK ( 18 ). I've set `dex.force.jumbo=true` on my project.properties and also I've tried with `set dex.force.jumbo=true`

But without lucky :(, any ideas ?

Comment: "jumbo" opcode support was present in ICS, but removed in JB.  See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/ab35b50311951feea3782151dd5422ee944685c2

Comment: did you ever fix this? Ran into the same issue and neither `dex.force.jumbo=true` nor increasing the eclipse memory to 8GB helped. Interesting fact: it only happens when running the app from Eclipse, not when exporting to an `.apk`

Answer (score 12):

Try adding `dex.force.jumbo=true` to your `project.properties` file

Answer (score 5):

For intellij or Android studio users: Settings - Android Compiler - DEX, you can check the flag.

However you *MUST* rebuild your project, otherwise you will still see the same error.

Answer (score 2):

With latest Android Studio and flag "force jumbo" checked on Android Studio compiler settings, this problem disappear.

Hope that help to someone.