# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration

Tags: android

I am using paypalSDK2.9.7.jar file and i am using eclipse ADT. I download this jar file from paypal site. I user this jar in this way right click project properties --> java build path --> add external jar --> find location --> selected paypalSDK2.9.7.jar --> click apply.. but i am facing  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration**.. If i am copy and paste paypalSDK2.9.7.jar in libs folder and right click on jar --> add build path i have done, but in this case i am facing **Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 66315 into a non-jumbo instruction!** error. Please tell me how i can fix these and run my app successfully

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this if it fits to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970957/cannot-compile-unable-to-execute-dex-cannot-merge-non-jumbo-instruction

Answer (score 0):

Use this SDK [Paypal jar](https://codeload.github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/zip/master)

Use this jar and some manifest file put in your project according to this example.